# My first Push notification not works if other notification comes

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I m facing an issue in android push notification, As title suggests, **My first Push notification not works if other notification comes**

here is my code

of MyNotification.Java

```
public class MyNotifications {

public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Context _context;

public MyNotifications(Context context) {
    _context = context;
}

public void SetNotification(int drawable, String sender, String msg,
        String story_ID, Class<?> cls) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(drawable, sender
            + ":" + msg, System.currentTimeMillis());
    notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    long[] vibrate = { 100, 100, 200, 300 };
    notifyDetails.vibrate = vibrate;
    notifyDetails.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
    notifyDetails.ledOnMS = 300;
    notifyDetails.ledOffMS = 1000;
    notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    // notifyDetails.number=4;
    notifyDetails.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    Context context = _context;
    CharSequence contentTitle = sender;
    CharSequence contentText = msg;
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // bundle.putBoolean(AppConfig.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    notifyIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("NEWS_SECTION", "PUSH_NOTIFICATION");
    notifyIntent.putExtra("STORY_ID", story_ID);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0,
            notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
            intent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(story_ID), notifyDetails);
}
}
```

im calling this like this

```
MyNotifications notifications_Ahmul_Akhbar = new MyNotifications(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    notifications_Ahmul_Akhbar.SetNotification(
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher, "الفرات نيوز",
                            story_title, story_id, Articles.class);
```

issue is described in my below image
[image]

Comment: its Q mobile A11 noir android 4.0

Comment: You should start using [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) rather than using Notification class directly

Comment: @hoomi Call requires API level 16 (current min is 11): android.app.Notification.Builder#build. and I have set minSDK to 11. I have to support the app upto android 4.0

Comment: @hoomi app crashed with this exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build

Comment: @QadirHussain you could use the support library. "Builder class for Notification objects. Provides a convenient way to set the various fields of a Notification and generate content views using the platform's notification layout template. If your app supports versions of Android as old as API level 4, you can instead use NotificationCompat.Builder, available in the Android Support library"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, this will work...

change this

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0,
            notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

to this

```
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
int count=1;

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context,(int) (Math.random() * 100),        notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,intent);
mNotificationManager.notify(count, notifyDetails);

count = count + 1;
```